# C# tweetinvi code 408

Tags: c#, tweetinvi

i am trying to learn connecting C# to Twitter by using `tweetinvi`.

i have no problem while connecting with `Twitter Key` and `Twitter Token`

then i debug my code, noticed `null` value on `User.GetAuthenticatedUser()`

however, i'm already authorize the twitter apps with my own twitter account.

Why does `User.GetAuthenticatedUser()` return `Null` Value ?

i got the following picture while trying to pass the error into `Message Box`
[image]

how do i resolve this  ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Tweetinvi;


namespace Twitdesk
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Cl_Tweetinvi twitinvi;
        Command cmd = new Command();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            twitinvi = new Cl_Tweetinvi();
            var AuthenticatedUser = User.GetAuthenticatedUser();
            if(AuthenticatedUser == null)
            {
                var latestException = ExceptionHandler.GetLastException();
                MessageBox.Show(latestException.ToString());
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else
            {
                var settings = AuthenticatedUser.GetAccountSettings();
            }

            var tweets = Timeline.GetHomeTimeline();            
            this.Text = cmd.title;
            MessageBox.Show("done");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that you have not initialized your credentials.

You need to call `Auth.SetUserCredentials("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET", "ACCESS_TOKEN", "ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET");` before performing any operation.

When you have invoked this line any operation will be using these credentials.

Please take a quick look at the [wiki](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Introduction) for more information. Or let me know if you still encounter any problem.

Though the problem could be different as the error message seems to indicate that you have a timeout problem. Normally authentication problems return 401 exception.

Comment: hi, i made some update and your code was already written. i was wondering why `AuthenticatedUser` become `null`

Comment: nope, i don't know why `AuthenticatedUser` return `Null`, because there's my own twitter account using my twitter apps.

Comment: `AuthenticatedUser` returns null because Twitter is returning an exception. The default behavior of Tweetinvi is to return null when an query fails.

Comment: I am going to investigate further what could cause a Timeout exception from Twitter. Is your internet connection stable?

Comment: Do you have the elevated privileges required to get the email included? (`include_email=true`).

Comment: I have found out that the problem comes from the fact that you are not able to retrieve a response on time from Twitter. But what I do not understand is the fact that your Timeout is set to 10 seconds which should be more than enough to perform such a request.

Please let me know if your internet connection might have some problems. Whether you need a proxy, vpn...

Comment: yep, my internet connection was stable. and still i don't know if there's something wrong with my code, or my twitter application.

i didn't set my Timout into 10seconds. should i change the value now ?

Comment: I don't think you should change the default settings. Could you try to go on https://apigee.com/console/twitter and see if this is working properly for you.

Comment: I will be happy to help you solve your problem but I think that we will have to have a live session in which I would be able to see your the application running in live. If you are happy with this please post a message on https://gitter.im/linvi/tweetinvi and I will reply to you privately.